# Get count of java classes loaded per library

Tags: java, regex, sed, classloader

In the [AWS re:invent presentation](https://d1.awsstatic.com/events/reinvent/2019/REPEAT_1_Best_practices_for_AWS_Lambda_and_Java_SVS403-R1.pdf) on Lambda performance (highly recommend) on pp.33-34 the author lists the count of classes loaded within each library using the following command:

```
java -cp my.jar -verbose:class Handler | grep '\[Loaded' | grep '.jar\]' | sed -r 's/\[Loaded \([^A-Z]*\)[\$A-Za-z0-9]*from.*\]/\1/g' | sort | uniq -c | sort
```

This basically extracts the namespace up to but not including the first capital letter, which is the class name. The output is supposed to look something like this:

```
143 com.fasterxml.jackson
219 org.apache.http
373 com.google
507 com.amazonaws
```

However this only works with the Java 8 class loader logs, which have the following format (this example should output `java.io`):

```
[Loaded java.io.Serializable from shared objects file]
```

The class loader logs as of Java 9+ have this different format:

```
[0.041s][info][class,load] java.io.Serializable source: jrt:/java.base
```

How does the `sed` command need to be updated to produce the same output as above?

I've tried the following, but the entire line is extracted in the regex group, not just the class library. I'm also running on a Mac, so I had to add a `-r` flag and remove some of the escape characters:

```
java -cp my.jar -verbose:class Handler | grep '[class,load]' | grep '.jar' | sed -r 's/.*\[class,load\] ([^A-Z]*)[$A-Za-z0-9]*source.*/\1/g'
```

Comment: This returns `java.io`, not sure if it's what you expect: `echo "[0.041s][info][class,load] java.io.Serializable source: jrt:/java.base" | cut -d ' ' -f2 | sed -r 's/([a-z.]+)\.[A-Z].*/\1/g'`

Comment: Yes, `java.io` is the expected output in that example (I clarified that in the question). Using `cut` is a great idea, since it simplifies the regex. I tried your solution and it works! Thank you! If you post as an answer with a brief explanation, I can select it.

Comment: In case [tag:awk] is acceptable: `… | awk 'sub(/\.[[:upper:]_].*/,"",$2){print $2}'` strips classname from blank-delimited field no. 2 and prints it.

Comment: You can't do arithmetic in sed so it shouldn't be considered when you want to count anything. Just use a small, simple awk command instead of a pipeline with a bunch of different commands. If you want help then ask a new question since you already accepted an answer to this one but this time tag it with awk.

Comment: Regarding "I'm also running on a Mac, so I had to add a -r flag` - Macs come with BSD sed which doesn't have a `-r` argument. Only older versions of GNU sed hav a `-r` argument to enable EREs - the same functionality is provided by `-E` in newer versions of sed in in BSD sed as you'd have by default on a Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the record has fields space separated we can take advantage of `cut` to get the desired field and then use `sed` to extract the package substring. The `([a-z.]+)\.[A-Z].*` regex looks for lower case letters and dots until the first dot followed by an upper case letter.

```
echo "[0.041s][info][class,load] java.io.Serializable source: jrt:/java.base" | cut -d ' ' -f2 | sed -E 's/([a-z.]+)\.[A-Z].*/\1/g'
```

Result:

```
java.io
```

If a `sed` only solution is preferred this command will do `grep` and `cut` jobs as well:

```
echo "[0.041s]..." | sed -nE '/class,load/ s/[^ ]+ ([^ ]+)/\1/ ; s/([a-z.]+)\.[A-Z].*/\1/p'
```

grep   : `/class,load/`
cut    : `s/[^ ]+ ([^ ]+)/\1/`
extract: `s/([a-z.]+)\.[A-Z].*/\1/p`

Comment: Wow, this solution actually works in both versions of the log format, since you're cutting by space and extracting the second token, which is the fully qualified classname in both cases. Major improvement, thanks!

Comment: @DV82XL Just tried doing the grep, cut and sed with sed only, if you confirm it works I can add to the answer : `sed -nr '/class,load/ s/[^ ]+ ([^ ]+)/\1/ ; s/([a-z.]+)\.[A-Z].*/\1/p'`

Comment: Yes, that produces identical results. Please feel free to append that to your answer. To be honest, I prefer the first solution since it's more readable and still very fast, but we can file that under personal preference.